# Express subapps communication

Tags: node.js, express

I have 2 subapps which are mounted like this:

```
//server.js

app.use('/am/api', subapp1)
app.use('/ucm/api', subapp2)
```

Each subapp returns an express router instance, e.g.:

```
//subapp1
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/msgs/:msg_id')
  .get(fn);

export default router
```

```
//subapp2
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/users/:user_id')
  .get(fn);

export default router
```

I want to make these subapps talk to each other, like subapp1 needs data from subapp2. Is there a best practice how to do that? I do not want any file dependencies between these subapps. I need a clean interface.

Comment: What's unclean about sharing common code placed in separate files? Other solutions, like `subapp1` making requests to `subapp2`, would be much less clean IMO.

Comment: In future I see that each subapp may grow and can be separated as microservices. If they are dependent on each others' files, it will be difficult but if they talk through an interface, its better. Today it can be common file that they both share, tomorrow it can be through rest calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution is to have separated service and make this communication inside this service. For example:

service.js:

```
const service = {};

service.action1 = function () {
  console.log('Communication with subapp2.');
}

service.action2 = function () {
  console.log('Communication with subapp1.');
}

module.exports = service;
```

In routes:

```
const service = require('./service');

subapp1 = function () {
  service.action1();
}

subapp2 = function () {
  service.action2();
}
```